Angular CLI: ng update fails due to certificate verification
Today I tried to update from Angular 17 to Angular 18. I am in a company with a custom proxy for the npm registry (uses a Nexus Repository for private packages). So we have disabled certificate validation in our npm config.

I get this error:
(node:12304) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
× Migration failed: request to https-nexus/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

So I tried to get more information about this, and I found some info.
Found several related issues:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10596
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10689
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9646

According to them, in a version of Angular CLI the problem seems to have been fixed, I've also tried the solutions mentioned, but it doesn't work on my side.
Also found this posts:

Unable to verify the first certificate in Nodejs while making request and cant install packages using npm
unable to verify the first certificate when running npm install

But didn't help me, first because they are not Angular related and second because they're too old.
My npm config:
https-proxy = "proxy"
no_proxy = "nexus"
progress = true
; "env" config from environment

registry = "https-nexus"
strict-ssl = false
unsafe-perm = true


; "cli" config from command line options

global = true

Window user env var:
HTTP_PROXY=proxy
HTTPS_PROXY=proxy
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,.private-proxy
NODE_OPTIONS=--max-http-header-size=200000
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY=https-nexus
NPM_CONFIG_STRICT_SSL=false
NPM_CONFIG_UNSAFE_PERM=true

Angular version
Angular CLI: 17.3.8
Node: 20.12.1
Package Manager: npm 10.8.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 17.3.12
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1703.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.3.8
@angular-devkit/core            17.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.3.8
@angular/cdk                    17.3.10
@angular/cli                    17.3.8
@angular/material               17.3.10
@schematics/angular             17.3.8
ng-packagr                      17.3.0
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.4.5
zone.js                         0.14.8

npm up or npm i <package> commands work successfully. But when I try ng add or ng update, those fail. Do you have any ideas about how to solve this?
Thanks !
I tried to create a local .npmrc with config:
strict-ssl = false

Tried to add process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'; in node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
Tried to find npm.js (like in GithHub issue) but doesn't exist in my version
Tried to run with line NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED like NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 ng update (for Linux). I am in Windows with PowerShell so I run the command with $env:NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0; ng update
Unfortunately, all these solutions have failed.
